# How to insert \x into NSString object

Tags: objective-c, io

I am trying to print data to a bluetooth printer.  In order to do this I need to send hex to the printer.  I have been successfully doing this by sending commands such as

@"\x1b\x7b\x01"
@"\x1b\x7b\x00"

These are all static commands.  I now need to take some data, a NSString, convert it to hex, and then send it to the printer.  I tried several different ways, most of which from this site, but cannot get it to work.

I know this doesn't work but I would like to do the following:

```
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; i++ )
{
    [hexString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\x%@",[str characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

- - hexString is the string I am trying to create and return.  str is the string I am trying turn into hex.  For example, 11111111 or abcdefg.

I have tried a variety of things all with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

dreamlax is right, you should use `NSData`. You could do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *hexTable = @{@"0" : @0,
                           @"1" : @1,
                           @"2" : @2,
                           @"3" : @3,
                           @"4" : @4,
                           @"5" : @5,
                           @"6" : @6,
                           @"7" : @7,
                           @"8" : @8,
                           @"9" : @9,
                           @"a" : @10,
                           @"b" : @11,
                           @"c" : @12,
                           @"d" : @13,
                           @"e" : @14,
                           @"f" : @15};

NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < str.length; i+=2 ) {
    NSString *substring1 = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    NSString *substring2 = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i+1, 1)];
    char valueHigh = [hexTable[substring1] charValue];
    char valueLow = [hexTable[substring2] charValue];
    char result = valueHigh*0x10 + valueLow;
    [data appendBytes:&result length:1];
}
```

Comment: This creates a string containing a backslash, an x, followed by a string, but the OP's original codes e.g. `@"\x1b\x7b\x00"` are supposed to contain only three bytes, the escape byte (\x1b or \033 or ASCII code 27), a command byte and a parameter byte (I'm assuming). I don't think the printer is expecting a hexadecimal representation of these bytes I think it is expected the actual bytes themselves. If this is the case, `NSString` is the wrong class to use.

Comment: The question was how to create a string like `@"\x1b\x7b\x00"`, not whether or not to use `NSString` in that case.

Comment: And your solution doesn't work. It creates the equivalent of `@"\\x..."` not `@"\x..."`. The strings won't match. Your code will produce an actual backslash in the resulting string whereas his strings `@"\x1B\x7B\x00"` have no backslash in them at all.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll update my answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right I should be using NSData...just figured that out this with another issue.  So how would I covert an ASCII string to Hex in NSData (think I am saying that right)?

Comment: I updated my answer. Where does your original hex string come from?

Answer (score 2):

for using "\" you need to escape one "\" more in your format it should be looking like this `"\\x%@"`
basically `\` is a [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) using in many of the languages

e.g if you use

```
NSLog(@"\\"); // output is one backslash
NSLog(@"\\\\"); // output is two backslashes
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are for storing text. If you want to store arbitrary bytes use `NSData` instead. In particular, when interfacing with external hardware, I think in general you want to avoid using `NSString` especially because strings are always assumed to contain text, but it appears as though your printer is expecting binary data (which you are simply only **representing** in hexadecimal). Things like `NUL` bytes (`\x00` or `\0`) do not play nicely with `NSString` but they do play nicely with `NSData`.

```
const char boldOnBytes[] = { 0x1b, 0x7b, 0x01 };
NSData *boldOn = [NSData dataWithBytes:boldOnBytes length:sizeof boldOnBytes];

const char boldOffBytes[] = { 0x1b, 0x7b, 0x00 };
NSData *boldOff = [NSData dataWithBytes:boldOffBytes length:sizeof boldOffBytes];
```

(I have no idea what your actual codes do)

To get the bytes again, you can use for example:

```
// assume you have a function called sendFunction which accepts a handle to the
// printer, the bytes to send, and a length of how many bytes to send.
sendFunction(printerHandle, [boldOn bytes], [boldOn length]);
```